# How to display some content of Div from the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the content of div in such a way that it will display only the last 3 list items and the rest of the content will be hidden.

```css
.wrapper {
height : 100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum eu ipsum at lectus rutrum interdum.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>bottom Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>bottom Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>bottom Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to apply the `height` property but it will apply to the top content rather than the bottom content.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to do that. `nth-last-child(-n+3)` will target last 3 elements.

```
li{
  display:none
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  display:list-item;
}
```

---

For **divs**, you can also **use the same CSS with few tweaks**. Assuming, the ***parent div*** has a main class

```
.main div{
  display:none;
}

.main div:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  display:block;
}
```

**Working Code**

```css
li {
  display: none
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  display: list-item;
}

.main div {
  display: none;
}

.main div:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li>Vestibulum eu ipsum at lectus rutrum interdum.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
    <li>Nulla ac dui eu velit semper vehicula.</li>
    <li>bottom Ut quis eros at tortor imperdiet viverra in a odio.</li>
    <li>bottom Morbi at erat non est dignissim suscipit quis nec nunc.</li>
    <li>bottom Etiam vitae velit lacinia, rutrum nulla eget, suscipit mauris.</li>
  </ul>
</div>



<div class='main'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose, If there is no li element under the main tag. There are many other div tag under the wrapper. Do you have any solution for it.

Comment: @ShivaniPatel: UPdated. Check please

Comment: It is working properly. I want to show my actual problem. Please go to this site http://clientapp.narola.online/hde/251029/test/ it will pop-up chatbot after sever seconds and refer this screenshot. http://prntscr.com/of3g28

Answer (score 0):

User CSS selection -

```
 li:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all of the `li` elements apart from the last 3:

```
$(".wrapper ul li").slice(0, -3).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script on bottom of page:

```
var len =$('.wrapper li').length -3;
$(".wrapper li:lt("+len+")").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements in the comment section, I assume you may be want to do something like this.

In this code when a user clicks on the text box it will only show the bottom 3 div elements and the rest will be hidden.

Here is the JS function and the HTML code. Hope this helps.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var div_count = document.getElementsByTagName("div").length; 
    for (var i = 0; i <= div_count; i++) {
        var x = document.getElementById("div" + i);

        if (i < div_count - 4) {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="div0">
            This is my 1st div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div1">
            This is my 2nd div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            This is my 3rd div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div3">
            This is my 4th div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div4">
            This is my 5th div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div5">
            This is my 6th div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div6">
            This is my 7th div element.
        </div>
        <div id="div7">
            This is my 8th div element.
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="" onClick="myFunction();" id="textbox1">
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</head>
```